# What are the Similarities between Dictionary and Array data types?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there any Similarities between data type Dictionary and data type Array. If there are any what are them?

Comment: For Java, you will need to look into HashMaps.

Comment: There is no similarity. You might want to check HashMap in Java (which is Dictionary in Python) or Lists in Python (which is Array / List in Java).

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz Not exactly. Both data structures are mapping keys on values. Its just that array keys are consecutive int values. But in the end, both data structures have a m(k)->v semantic ... there are actually programming languages where arrays are nothing but a specialized implementation of maps.

Comment: The similarity is they are both containers of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary *maps* strings to values.

An array maps integers to values.

That is about it!

So, seriously: in the end, both data structures map a "key set" to values. For dictionaries, the keys can of (almost) arbitrary type, without any constraint on them (besides being "hash able"). Whereas an array maps a consecutive range of ints to values.

From that point of view, arrays and dicts/maps are doing the same thing, but in the end, how you use them is very different.

And just for completeness: of course, the "underlying" similarity is that both are "containers": objects that "own" multiple other objects.

Comment: "For dictionaries, the keys can of arbitrary type, without any constraint on them. " keys must be hashable.